# Why my create Event function is giving me "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Now I am working to fix the Administration Area web page for my ASP.NET Core MVC project. I have an issue with my `Create` function. I don't have any idea where is coming from.

I am able to access my `Create` web page. It looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqLWf.png)

The issue is that when I fill out the form and press the Save button I got an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'ArtGallery.Core.Models.Administrator.EventCreateInputViewModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'ArtGallery.Core.Models.Home.IndexViewModel'

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjExR.png)

Here is my create function in the `EventController`:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return this.View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EventCreateInputViewModel model)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return this.View(model);
    }

    await eventService.AddAsync(model);

    return Redirect("All");
}
```

My `EventService` for the create is:

```
public async Task AddAsync(EventCreateInputViewModel model)
{
     await _applicationDbContext.Events.AddAsync(new Event
     {
         Name = model.Name,
         Price = model.Price,
         Date = DateTime.ParseExact(model.Date,
                 DateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
         Description = model.Description,
     });

     await _applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Create view page markup and code:

```
@using ArtGallery.Core.Models.Administrator;
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model EventCreateInputViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Event";
    Layout = "/Areas/Administration/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    var evenOne = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EventType;
    var evenTwo = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TicketType;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <form asp-area="Administration" asp-controller="Event" asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="form-lable"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="form-lable"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <label asp-for="Date" class="form-lable"></label>
                <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <label asp-for="Type" class="form-lable"></label>
                <select asp-for="Type" asp-items="@evenOne" class="form-control">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Please select...</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">InPerson</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="2">Online</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <label asp-for="TicketSelection" class="form-lable"></label>
                <select asp-for="TicketSelection" asp-items="@evenTwo" class="form-control">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Please select...</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">Free</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="2">Paid</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="TicketSelection" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="form-lable"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This view is working and look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8P86.png)

I try to fix the create function by implementing an additional service method:

```
   public async Task<bool> CreateEventAsync(string name, decimal price, string date,
        string type, string ticketSelection, string description)
    {
        bool isCreated = false;
        var createEvent = new EventCreateInputViewModel();

        if (createEvent != null)
        {
            createEvent.Name = name;
            createEvent.Price = price;
            createEvent.Date = date;
            createEvent.Type = Enum.Parse<EventType>(type);
            createEvent.TicketSelection = Enum.Parse<TicketType>(ticketSelection);
            createEvent.Description = description;

            // this._eventRepo.AddAsync(createEvent);
            // await this._eventRepo.SaveChangesAsync();

            _applicationDbContext.Events.Add(new Event()
            {
                Name = name,
                Price = price,
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(date),
                Type = Enum.Parse<EventType>(type),
                TicketSelection = Enum.Parse<TicketType>(ticketSelection),
                Description = description,
                CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,

            });

            _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return isCreated;
    }
```

It seems that looking for my Index DTO. My index for the Home page with the public access should only get `UpcomingEvents` and `LatestBlogs` not saving events. My create page has to create event and save them in "All Events" web page.

The Create DTO that I am using is `EventCreateInputViewModel`, but when I try to save my new event it looking for my Index DTO. I don't have idea why I am getting this issue. It look like to me is my Create page is trying to save my new events using Index DTO.

Could somebody help me with this issue, please? Does my code have any issues that could cause this error?

Comment: At a guess, your `All` View requires a different view model.
Put a breakpoint in your controller `Create` method and see which branch is failing - there's 2 different views involved, depending on whether the model is valid or not.

Comment: Could you please share your `EventCreateInputViewModel` location? Additionally, share `Administration Area web page ` structures.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Here is a Pastebin to  your request https://pastebin.com/zsvnZvqM